# Homework: Implementing the Z algorithm in python, it's really slow, slower than naive string search

Tags: python, algorithm, string-matching

I have to implement the Z algorithm and use it to search a target text for a specific pattern. I've implemented what I thought was the correct algorithm and search function using it but it's really slow. For the naive implementation of string search I consistently got times lower than 1.5 seconds and for the z string search I consistently got times over 3 seconds (for my biggest test case) so I have to be doing something wrong. The results seem to be correct, or were at least for the few test cases we were given. The code for the functions mentioned in my rant is below:

```
import sys
import time

# z algorithm a.k.a. the fundemental preprocessing algorithm
def z(P, start=1, max_box_size=sys.maxsize):
    n = len(P)
    boxes = [0] * n
    l = -1
    r = -1

    for k in range(start, n):
        if k > r:
            i = 0
            while k + i < n and P[i] == P[k + i] and i < max_box_size:
                i += 1
            boxes[k] = i
            if i:
                l = k
                r = k + i - 1
        else:
            kp = k - l
            Z_kp = boxes[kp]
            if Z_kp < r - k + 1:
                boxes[k] = Z_kp
            else:
                i = r + 1
                while i < n and P[i] == P[i - k] and i - k < max_box_size:
                    i += 1
                boxes[k] = i - k    
                l = k
                r = i - 1
    return boxes

# a simple string search
def naive_string_search(P, T):
    m = len(T)
    n = len(P)
    indices = []
    for i in range(m - n + 1):
        if P == T[i: i + n]:
            indices.append(i)
    return indices

# string search using the z algorithm.
# The pattern you're searching for is simply prepended to the target text
# and than the z algorithm is run on that concatenation
def z_string_search(P, T):
    PT = P + T
    n = len(P)
    boxes = z(PT, start=n, max_box_size=n)
    return list(map(lambda x: x[0]-n, filter(lambda x: x[1] >= n, enumerate(boxes))))
```

Comment: easiest may be run with pypy

Comment: How big is your largest test case?

Comment: For example on this case P:aaa T:aaaaaa your algorithms yield different results.

Comment: So whats your question?

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation of z-function `def z(..)` is algorithmically and asymptotically good.

It has O(m + n) time complexity in the worst case while implementation of naive string search has O(m*n) time complexity in the worst case. I believe that the problem lies in your test cases (they are weak).

For example if we take this test case:

```
T = ['a'] * 1000000 
P = ['a'] * 1000
```

we will get this time for z-function calculation:

```
real    0m0.650s
user    0m0.606s
sys 0m0.036s
```

and for naive string matching:

```
real    0m8.235s
user    0m8.071s
sys 0m0.085s
```

PS: You should understand that there are lots of test cases where a naive string matching works in linear time too, for example:

```
T = ['a'] * 1000000 
P = ['a'] * 1000000
```

Thus the worst case for a naive string matching is where the function should apply a pattern and check against it many times. In the case above it will do only one check because of the lengths of the input (it can't apply the pattern from index 1 so it won't continue).